# template specialization -->error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'GameObjectImpl'

Tags: qt, c++11, templates

I am  writing a Game & I have a  interface called GameObject.
This game object is implemented by derived objects say planet , comet , asteroids etc. Now I need type_index of these objects in different functions.

To achieve this I define virtual function in GameObject & want to use template pattern  with type of derived class . unfortunately I am getting error 
 **error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'GameObjectImpl'
template  struct GameObjectImpl : GameObject**
                                 ^

Below is the source code

```
struct GameObject
{
    virtual ~GameObject() = default;
    virtual type_index type() const = 0;
};
template <typename T> struct GameObjectImpl<T> : GameObject //error
{
    type_index type() const override
    {
        return typeid(T);
    }
};

struct Planet : GameObjectImpl<Planet>{};
struct Asteriod : GameObjectImpl<Asteriod>{};
```

Can you please let me know how to get rid of this error.Pl note i am learning template pattern so wants to use only template

Comment: `template <typename T> struct GameObjectImpl : GameObject { ... };` Drop the `<T>`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That looks more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a template

```
template <typename T> 
  struct GameObjectImpl : 
    GameObject
```

This is a template *specialization*

```
template <typename T> 
  struct GameObjectImpl<T> : 
    GameObject
```

And probably not a valid specialization at that (it doesn't seem to specialize anything). The syntax `GameObjectImpl<T>` requires that a template named `GameObjectImpl` is already defined somewhere.

In all likelihood you want to define a template, not a template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

To specialize a template, there mush exist a template to specialize:

```
template <typename T>
struct GameObjectImpl {

};
```

Take into account that if you specialize a class template, you must also specialize all the member functions